Bound of a compactly supported distribution
$u: \mathrm{C}^{\infty}(\Bbb R) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a linear map
$$u(\varphi):=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{\varphi\left(\frac{1}{j}\right)-\varphi\left(-\frac{1}{j}\right)}{j}$$
The question is to find all compact $K \subseteq\Bbb R$ such that:
$$\tag⋆
\exists c \geqslant 0, m \in \mathbb{N}:\; |u(\varphi)| ⩽ c \sum_{\alpha=0}^m \sup_K\left|\varphi^{(\alpha)}\right|\; \text{for all $\varphi \in \mathrm{C}^{\infty}(\Bbb R)$.}$$
(see also nlab)

To prove $\operatorname{supp}(u)\subseteq K$
The support of $u$, denoted by $\operatorname{supp}(u)$, is the set of
points $x$ having no open neighbourhood $Ω$ such that $u(φ)=0$ for all $φ \in\mathrm{C}^{\infty}(\Bbb R)$ supported in $Ω$.
For all $j\in\Bbb Z\setminus\{0\}$, There exists $φ\in \mathrm{C}^{\infty}(\Bbb R)$ such that $φ(x)\ne0$ in a small neighborhood of $\frac1j$.
So the support of $u$ is $\left\{\frac{1}{j}: j \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus\{0\}\right\} \cup\{0\}$.
For all $x\notin K$, for all open neighborhood $Ω$ of $x$, since $Ω\setminus K$ is an open neighborhood of $x$, for any $φ$ supported in $Ω\setminus K$, then (⋆) implies that $u(φ)=0$, so $x\notin\operatorname{supp}(u)$. Hence $\operatorname{supp}(u)\subseteq K$.

To prove $0$ is an interior point of $K$
If $0$ is not an interior point of $K$, we prove that (⋆) doesn't hold.
Since $\operatorname{supp}(u)\subseteq K$, we have $0\in K$, but $0$ is not an interior point of $K$, so it is a boundary point of $K$.
$\Bbb R\setminus K$ is an open set, so it is the union of countable disjoint intervals.
Since $0$ is a boundary point of $\Bbb R\setminus K$, we can take a sufficiently large $k\in\Bbb N^+$ such that there is a closed interval $[a,b]\subseteq(\frac1{k+1},\frac1k)\cup(-\frac1k,-\frac1{k+1})$ and $[a,b]\subseteq\Bbb R\setminus K$.
WLOG $[a,b]\subseteq(\frac1{k+1},\frac1k)$.
Then there is $φ\in \mathrm{C}^\infty(\Bbb R)$ such that
$$φ|_{[b,\infty)}=1$$
and
$$φ|_{(-\infty,a]}=0$$
Then
$\varphi(\frac1j)=1$ for all $j \le k$.
$\varphi(\frac1j)=0$ for all $j > k$.
$\varphi^{(\alpha)}(\frac1j)=0$ for all $\alpha>0,j \in \mathbb{Z}$
$\varphi^{(\alpha)}(-\frac1j)=0$ for all $\alpha\ge0,j \in \mathbb{Z}$
Then (⋆) reads
$$|u(\varphi)| ⩽ c(1+0+0+\cdots)=c$$
but $u(\varphi)=\sum_{j=1}^k\frac1j>c$ for large $k$. So (⋆) doesn't hold.

If $K$ contains $\operatorname{supp}(u)$ and $0$ is interior point of $K$, to prove (⋆) holds
Since $0$ is interior point of $K$, $[-\frac1k,\frac1k]\subseteq K$ for some $k$.
Set $m=1$.
For $\varphi \in \mathrm{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$, by mean value inequality
$$
\left|\frac{\varphi\left(\frac{1}{j}\right)-\varphi\left(-\frac{1}{j}\right)}{j}\right| \leqslant\frac2{j^2}\sup_K\left|\varphi^{\prime}\right|\\
\implies\left|\sum_{j>k}\frac{\varphi\left(\frac{1}{j}\right)-\varphi\left(-\frac{1}{j}\right)}{j}\right| \leqslant\left(\sum_{j>k}\frac2{j^2}\right) \sup_K\left|\varphi^{\prime}\right| .
$$
By triangle inequality
$$|\langle u, \varphi\rangle| \leqslant\left(\sum_{1\leqslant j\leqslant k}\frac2j\right)\sup_K|\varphi|+\left(\sum_{j>k}\frac2{j^2}\right) \sup_K\left|\varphi^{\prime}\right| .
$$

So the answer is:
$K$ contains $\operatorname{supp}(u)$ and $0$ is an interior point of $K$.
